# how can I transfer the string value of a variable in Azure Cosmos DB using the Bot Framework Composer V2?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, bot-framework-composer

To enter data into the Cosmos DB Tables, I use this addition (https://github.com/tomlm/iciclecreek.bot/tree/master/source/Libraries/Iciclecreek.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Database.AzureStorage). The problem is that I cannot pass the value of the variable to the entity. Only the name of the variable is passed, not its content. My variable only contains a string value and is outputted for validation without any problem.
In this add-on, I use the Entity Operation block.

```
//Content Entity
// ${dialog.cosmos.name} - my variable whose value needs to be passed
{
    "partitionKey": "KeyP2",
    "rowKey": "RowKeyR1",
    "nameUs": "${dialog.cosmos.name}",
    "surnameus": "feleni"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a property with all variables before the entity operation block. And then insert this property into the Entity.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqo75.png